# GoogleMaps - Actual Map not showing

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-maps

I was following this tutorial:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html --> Paragraph 6.0

Problem: My emulator runs perfectly fine and everything works good (it zooms and everything), however, the actual map is nothing but a grid. It states that I should be able to send coordinates via the emulator, but how?

Possible Solutions? - Is my API key not correct? Am I not sending the correct coordinates? (I click random numbers and letters)

Comment: check this out  http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-map-api-key.html

Comment: As everyone has said you need to get a debug api key which will be linked to your eclipse keystore (no one elses key will work) As far as sending coord's in the emulator you need to use the DDMS view in eclipse and the emulator control view (Show view if it's not open)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct. Normally that is a problem with your API key.

https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup

It is getting the coordinates but if it is not generating the map it is a definite api key problem.  You did request a key from google right using your java sdk keytool?

Comment: I used another application that required a key on my website and I tried re-using the key, but I'm guessing that's not alright to do

Answer (score 1):

You are using de debug.keystore, yo need to use other keystore, with other api key to run maps in a terminal.