# Blue screen in Android Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I am getting a blue screen when I load my Google Maps on Android. I don't know what I am doing wrong, this is my code for getting the locations:

```
MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapDire);
Route route = directions(new GeoPoint((int)(2*1E6),(int)(34*1E6)),
  new GeoPoint((int)(3*1E6),(int)(36*1E6)));
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think can be two things

- Your coordinates are 0,0 and the map is opening in the ocean
- Something wrong with your API Key

In the first case try zoom out a lot of times and try to see some continent.

In the second try to read the documentation or/and try this [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=awX5T-EwLPc)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I have this problem in my application and see below code in `onlocationchanged` method and resolve it.

```
LatLng myCoordinates = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
         mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myCoordinates));

    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 17.0f));

    marker.setPosition(myCoordinates);
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally blue screen means your Google API key didn't work.

[GoogleMaps - Actual Map not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11104155/933756)

Answer (score 0):

If your map is not showing, only grids/blank screen showing, that's because your Map API key is missing or incorrect. Sign up for Google Android Map API.

Try this [the link](https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

There could 3 reasons as to why You see blue screens

1. Your Long/Lat Points to Water region - or Ocean region, Invariably there's nothing wrong just you Long/Lat Pointing to Water which is blue in color.
2. Your Long/Lat is wrong and nothing comes up
3. Your API key is wrong which can be corrected on your Android manifest file
   *directory: Android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml*

Answer (score 0):

An additional possibility is that you need to add proguard rules to your proguard-rules.pro

```
# Google Maps
# Needed to avoid a blue screen map
-keep,allowoptimization class com.google.android.libraries.maps.** { *; }
-keep,allowoptimization class com.google.android.apps.gmm.renderer.** { *; }
```