# flutter google map widget shows blue screen

Tags: google-maps, flutter, google-cloud-platform

I'm using google_maps_flutter package.
When I use GoogleMap class, I can see blue square with Google logo.
I put API key on Android manifest file and I did every thing with Api key.
(I got API key from Google cloud Platform)

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113009/blue-screen-in-android-google-maps) is a similar post. Have a look on it and let me know if it works for you, otherwise, I'll investigate further.

Comment: sorry I couldn't find how to apply google map api v2 to my project... I'll try more. at first time I tried [link]https://www.raywenderlich.com/4466319-google-maps-for-flutter-tutorial-getting-started <-- v1 api like this. is this no use any more?

Comment: If the problem is with Google Map Api v2, please verify if you did the [following](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map-with-marker). Can you attach your code in order to look in what it's giving error?